# Fourier sine series, representation problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-series

Given $f(x) = \frac{\pi ^2}{2}-x^2$, find the sine series in $[0,\pi]$.

I have computed $$b_k = \frac{2}{\pi}\int _0^\pi f(x)\sin kx dx = \begin{cases} \frac{8}{\pi k^3}, &k\mbox{ odd}\\ \frac{2\pi}{k}, &k\mbox{ even}\end{cases} $$
Which is a bit confusing since the end goal is to find $$f(x)\sim \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\sin kx $$

Prior to simplifying I arrived at $$b_k = \frac{2}{\pi}\left [ \frac{\pi ^2k^2((-1)^k+1)-4((-1)^k-1)}{2k^3}\right ] $$
What do I have to do to get the series written in a "sensible" fashion?

Or would I simply use this very form of $b_k$ [it looks ugly, I have this standard-textbook-exercise-syndrome, all the solutions are pretty] and prove via comparison, that the series converges absolutely? [actually no. It would be sufficient, but it's not going to work.]

Comment: Should the integral run from $-\pi$ to $\pi$?

Comment: that runs into a problem. Namely the integral vanishes, which ought to be apparent. I don't understand why, but the textbook says we must integrate $0\to \pi$ and double the result. But then isn't that the sine series over $[-\pi,\pi]$. It's confusing :/

Comment: Or do we "artifcially" extend $f(x)$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ by making it odd?

Comment: I think it is so because your $f(x)$ is even.

Comment: the integral must be evaluated in a complete period. If the period is $\pi$ then you must adjust also the period of the sine to fit it.

Comment: That is correct, it should be $\sin(2kx)$.